# Read json value in where clause in sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
insert into #users(userid)
select userid
From maintableA
Inner join
(
    Select id 
    from maintable
    where  user_id=@createdby
) B  
    on A.id=B.id
```

The `@createdby` parameter contains JSON data with the following structure:

> {User:{"createdby":"23"}}

How can i get the value of "createdby" from this JSON?

Comment: What do you mean  getting `@createdby` value dynamically is the value look like the json?

Comment: @D-shih createdby value can be changed to any integer value like it can be 21 or 22 or 23 so on

Comment: I've edited your question in the hope it would make it clearer. Please [edit] it if I misunderstood the original intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
DECLARE @createdby varchar(100) = '{"User":{"createdby":"23"}}';

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@createdby, '$.User.createdby');
```

Result: `23`

So, with your code it would look like this:

```
insert into #users(userid)
select userid
From maintableA
Inner join
(
    Select id 
    from maintable
    where  user_id = JSON_VALUE(@createdby, '$.User.createdby')
) as B  on A.id=B.id
```

Comment: i cannot hard code {"User":{"createdby":"23"}}..... it can be 22 or 21 or any integer

Comment: The first code in the answer is just for a quick demonstration of the `json_value` function. You don't need to hard code anything.

Comment: how can i return value like this in output:  {User:{"createdby":"23"}}

Comment: Since it's a simple json, I think it would be easiest to construct the string yourself. Other options include using `For Json`, but it's going to be more work to get this kind of json value using `for josn` than constructing the string yourself.

Comment: how to use for json path ,root('User') without array wrapper

Comment: Like this: 
`DECLARE @Id int = 23;
SELECT @Id As 'User.createdby'
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`